# What is the symbol $\triangleq$?

Tags: notation

I came across this new symbol while reading a document about writing proofs, and I have never seen it before.

Comment: I've only seen it used to mean that the LHS is defined to be the RHS.

Comment: It is the eject button.

Comment: @copper.hat, awesome!!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It’s *is defined to be equal to*; it’s my preferred symbol, but the most common one is $:=$, and I’ve also seen $\overset{\text{def}}=$.

> For each $x\in X$ there is an open nbhd $U_x$ of $x$ such that ... . Then $\mathscr{U}\triangleq\{U_x:x\in X\}$ is ...

The $\triangleq$ indicates that $\mathscr{U}$ is being defined to be $\{U_x:x\in X\}$: we are not saying that some previously defined $\mathscr{U}$ is equal to the collection of these sets $U_x$.

Comment: +1, except that I don't agree with preferring this symbol ;)

Comment: The $\overset{\text{def}}=$ symbol is better exactly because it doesn't lead to this question being asked as often... But the triangle-equals looks neater inline, is faster to write by hand, and is language-independent. So they're evenly matched. So let's invent a new symbol, how about $\overset{\leftrightarrow}=$ implying that LHS is a shorthand for RHS.

Comment: +1 only because it is Brian's preferred symbol and that is a big deal!

Comment: the best is :=.

Comment: Some people might prefer $\triangleq$ because it is symmetrical.

Comment: I've always seen definitions as $\equiv$, but I like the look of $\triangleq$

Comment: @Karlo, wouldn't symmetry be undesirable, since it is the LHS that is being defined?

Comment: @Joe: The fact that it is predictably the lefthand side that is being distinguished means that symmetry of the sign is irrelevant. (And I find that it is virtually always clear from context whether something is being defined, so I see no need for a special symbol at all, save in very unusual circumstances.)

Comment: @Joe Indeed, that can be the case, for instance when you're saying $a:=b$, although $b$ should already have been defined before and $a$ not. On the other hand, when writing $a:=b\cdot c\cdot d$, is clearer that you are defining $a$. I guess it depends and it's a personal choice.

Comment: > _"... we are not saying that some previously defined $\mathscr{U}$ is equal to the collection of these sets $U_x$."_  $\quad$ You seem to suggest that such usage is erroneous and must be avoided. What symbol do you use instead, I wonder?

Comment: @paperskilltrees: I have no idea how you came to the conclusion that I was suggesting anything of the kind. I am simply pointing out the difference between $$\mathscr{U}\triangleq\{U_x:x\in X\}\,$$ which defines the symbol $\mathscr{U}$, and $$\mathscr{U}=\{U_x:x\in X\}\,$$ which asserts that some previously defined set $\mathscr{U}$ is equal to the set $\{U_x:,\in X\}$. In most contexts I would write $$\mathscr{U}=\{U_x:x\in X\}$$ for both of those meanings, but occasionally it is useful to distinguish definitions from statements that two previously defined things are equal.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was referring to when $\triangleq$ is used to mean "is equal, by a previously made definition", just like one would write $\stackrel{(23)}{=}$ meaning that "is equal, by virtue of formula (23)". Such usage of $\triangleq$ is a reference to a previously made definition and would be a verbatim copy of it or a very trivial specialisation, e.g.
$$\mathscr{U}_X := \{U_x:x\in X\}$$
and then
$$\mathscr{U}_Y\triangleq\{U_x:x\in Y\},$$
where $\triangleq$ is to emphasise that the equality is a trivial consequence of a definition and that no new definition has been made.

Comment: @paperskilltrees: Ah, okay; I very much doubt that I would ever use it that way. I would use a simple equals sign and add a brief explanation if I thought that one were really necessary.

Answer (score 17):

The symbol means it is "equal to by definition".

Answer (score -4):

It actually is defined as "estimates", and also means that the content on the two sides correlates or conforms to each other.

For further reference, see [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleichheitszeichen#Das_Gleichheitszeichen_und_seine_Abwandlungen) and [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2259/index.htm), the symbol is quite often used in (German?) academic context.

Comment: You are mistaking $\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\wedge}{=}$ for $\triangleq$.